# delete a row listview android

Tags: android, listview

I am trying to make a list with titles,descriptions and other data using custom listview in every row with delete imagebutton.

When I click on the ImageButton in row number 10 ,row number 5 from ListView is getting deleted!

[image]

myadapter :

```
public  static class ViewHolder {
    TextView favorites_title;
    TextView favorites_description;
    TextView favorites_date;
    ImageButton favorites_btn_delete ;
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    ViewHolder holder;
    if(convertView==null){
        /****** Inflate tabitem.xml file for each row ( Defined below ) *******/
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.favorites_list_row_layout, null);

        /****** View Holder Object to contain tabitem.xml file elements ******/

        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.favorites_title = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.favorites_title);
        holder.favorites_description = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.favorites_description);
        holder.favorites_date = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.favorites_date);
        holder.favorites_btn_delete = (ImageButton)convertView.findViewById(R.id.favorites_btn_delete); 
       /************  Set holder with LayoutInflater ************/
        convertView.setTag( holder );
        holder.favorites_btn_delete.setTag(position);
    }
    else 
        holder=(ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
    holder.favorites_btn_delete.getTag();
    NewsItem newsItem = (NewsItem) listData.get(position);

    holder.favorites_title.setText(newsItem.getHeadline());
    holder.favorites_description.setText(newsItem.getDescription());
    holder.favorites_date.setText(newsItem.getDate());
    holder.favorites_btn_delete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Integer index = (Integer) v.getTag();
            int i = index.intValue();
            Log.e("Position",  String.valueOf(i));
        //  listData.remove(i);
        //  notifyDataSetChanged();

        }
    });
```

Comment: already you took convertview.getTag() so just pass the default position what you get from getview. listData.remove(position);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move `holder.favorites_btn_delete.setTag(position);` outside the `if else` or else the new `position` values will never be set as tag in the `Button` when `convertView` is not null and the old values will remain as tag

Answer (score 0):

holder.favorites_btn_delete.setOnClickListener(this);

outside the getview method

```
public void onClick(View v)
    {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Integer index = (Integer) v.getTag();
            int i = index.intValue();
            Log.e("Position",  String.valueOf(i));
          listData.remove(i);
        notifyDataSetChanged();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

use this code..it will help u..

apply onItem click listener on image button

```
@Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position, long arg3) {
         listData.remove(positon);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

Apply this on your activity.